# Bounds for recursive binomial process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a sequence of binomial random variables with the following law:
$$
Z_1 = \text{Bin}(n,p) \text{ and } Z_k = \text{Bin} (Z_{k-1}, p)
$$

I would like to bound the quantity $\frac{Z_k}{Z_1}$. By the law of total expectation, we can find that $E[Z_k] = E[E[Z_k|Z_{k-1}]] = \dots = p^{n-1}E[Z_1]$, intuitively we can see that $Z_k$ is roughly on the order of $Zp^{n-1}$

I would like to derive a bound that either confirms, or rejects, my intuition, i.e. a bound of the form
$$P(Z_k \leq Z_1p^{n-1}) \geq b_k$$

where $b_k$ is some (currently) unknown term. I believe that a bound based off of Azuma's inequality leads to non-informative bound.

Comment: Do you have an extra index $k$ in the equality you desire?

Comment: Yes, silly mistake, thank you

Comment: Not sure about how one can get the bound, but one can prove that $Z_k \sim \mbox{Bin}(n,p^k)$ for all $k \geq 1$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer are you sure? Consider $k = 2$ then $P(Z_2 = 0) = \sum_{j=0}^n P(Z_2 = 0|Z_1 = j)P(Z_1=j) = \sum_{j=0}^n {n \choose j}p^j(1-p)^n = (1-p^2)^n \neq (1-p)^{2n} = P(Q = 0)$ where $Q \sim \text{Bin}(n, p^2)$

Comment: @DumbPhuck I think if $Q \sim \mbox{Bin}(n,p^2)$ then $\mathbb P(Q=0) = (1-p^2)^n$, right? The other one, $(1-p)^{2n}$, is equal to $\mathbb P(Q'=0)$ where $Q' \sim \mbox{Bin}(2n,p)$. Anyway, the proof that I have of that particular assertion is via a coupling argument that I can include in the comments if required.